# Complexity Analysis of recursive subset calculation of an array

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote a code to calculate subsets of an array recursively. I am a little confused about the complexity of the code. I expect it to be of the form T(n) = T(n-1) = O(n). Please let me know if I am correct or wrong. Thank you.

```
def subsets(arr):
    """
    :param: arr - input integer array
    Return - list of lists (two dimensional array) where each list represents a subset
    TODO: complete this method to return subsets of an array
    """

    if len(arr) == 1:
        return [[], arr]
    
    outs = []
    elem = arr[0]
    next_elems = arr[1:]
    outs = subsets(next_elems)

    for each_elem in outs: 
        t1 = [elem] + each_elem 
        outs = outs + [t1]
    
    return outs
```

Below is the sample input and output for the code:
arr = [9, 12, 15]
output =  [[],
[15],
[12],
[12, 15],
[9],
[9, 15],
[9, 12],
[9, 12, 15]]

Comment: `T(n) = n * T(n-1)` is a formula for `n!`, not `n^2`. But it is also not correct for your code because not all of the recursive calls are on size `n-1`.

Comment: That said, your algorithm is not correct at all, because `subsets([1, 2])` returns `[]` which is (of course) not the correct result according to the specification. So there is not much use in analysing its time complexity.

Comment: @kaya3 thank you. Yes, i figured out the mistake and fixed it. With the fix, it should be O(n) right?

Comment: no, look at the first comment....

Comment: Your desired output has size `O(n * 2^n)`, so it is impossible for any algorithm to produce this output in a lower time complexity than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation is wrong, since after calling the function recursively on input size `n-1`, you loop over all the `2^(n-1)` results and at each iteration create a new array `t1` of size `O(n)`. So the recurrence relation should be

```
T(0) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + n * 2^(n-1)
```

Since

```
lim { T(n), for n->infinity } = n * 2^(n-1),
```

the asymptotic solution to this relation is

```
O(n * 2^(n-1)) = O(n * 2^n)
```